# PyQt Doesn't look like in Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

My problem is that when I am starting my App with Python I'm getting different elements size rather than in Designer. You can see it even in buttons in right top corner.

[image]
[image]
My main file looks like:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QButtonGroup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSpinBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("TrackerConfig.ui", self)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is my [`TrackerCofig.ui`](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZcTDZnMy)

Comment: try with: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: `app.setStyle("fusion")` changed it a little but doesn't help. The main problem is that Label, SpinBoxes, Edits are smaller. https://i.imgur.com/Bv6y179.png

Comment: try with: `QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)`

Comment: I tried `app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` - nothing changed

Comment: I don't know why but it helps when I just create a new project and copied all my widgets.

Comment: idk why pyQT makes me sick. QT is best with C++